# Excel userform causing secondary issues

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a user form with 5 list boxes, these contain list that are used to populate various textboxes to organise vehicles with drivers and loads. There are a total of 235 textboxes. 
I have changed a code I found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145421/vba-listbox-drag-drop) about using drag and drop. However I made some changes and when I tried to close the workbook it gave me a blue circle that was still there 45 minutes later. I removed all my changes and used the basic code and it was still causing issues. I have to go into task manager and physically stop the process, however I can not see what is causing the issues.

this is the code for the userform

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Ctrl As MSForms.Control
Dim LMB As ListBoxDragAndDropManager
Dim x As Integer

Set LBs = New Collection
For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(Ctrl) = "ListBox" Then
        Set LMB = New ListBoxDragAndDropManager
        Set LMB.ThisListBox = Ctrl
        LBs.Add LMB
    End If
Next
For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
        Set LMB = New ListBoxDragAndDropManager
        Set LMB.ThisTextBox = Ctrl
        LBs.Add LMB
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

this is in a stand alone module

```
Public DragSource As MSForms.ListBox
```

and this is in a class module

```
 Option Explicit
Private WithEvents pThisListBox As MSForms.ListBox
Private WithEvents pThisTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Friend Property Set ThisListBox(Ctrl As MSForms.ListBox)
    Set pThisListBox = Ctrl
End Property
Friend Property Get ThisListBox() As MSForms.ListBox
    Set ThisListBox = pThisListBox
End Property
Friend Property Set ThisTextBox(Ctrl As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set pThisTextBox = Ctrl
End Property
Friend Property Get ThisTextBox() As MSForms.TextBox
    Set ThisTextBox = pThisTextBox
End Property
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set DragSource = Nothing
    Set pThisListBox = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub pThisListBox_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, _
    ByVal Action As Long, _
    ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, _
    ByVal x As Single, _
    ByVal Y As Single, _
    ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, _
    ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim i As Long
    If DragSource Is pThisListBox Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    Effect = 1
    pThisListBox.AddItem Data.GetText
    With DragSource
        For i = 1 To .ListCount
            If .List(i - 1, 0) = Data.GetText Then
                .RemoveItem i - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub pThisTextBox_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, _
    ByVal Action As Long, _
    ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, _
    ByVal x As Single, _
    ByVal Y As Single, _
    ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, _
    ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim i As Long
    If DragSource Is pThisListBox Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    Effect = 1
    pThisTextBox.Value = DragSource
    With DragSource
        For i = 1 To .ListCount
            If .List(i - 1, 0) = Data.GetText Then
                .RemoveItem i - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub pThisListBox_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, _
    ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, _
    ByVal x As Single, _
    ByVal Y As Single, _
    ByVal DragState As Long, _
    ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, _
    ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Cancel = True
    Effect = 1
End Sub
Private Sub pThisListBox_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, _
    ByVal Shift As Integer, _
    ByVal x As Single, _
    ByVal Y As Single)
    Dim MyDataObject As DataObject
    Dim Effect As Integer
    If Button = 1 Then
        Set DragSource = pThisListBox
        Set MyDataObject = New DataObject
        If pThisListBox.Text = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        MyDataObject.SetText pThisListBox.Value
        Effect = MyDataObject.StartDrag
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub pThisListBox_Click()
    Dim Ctrl As MSForms.Control
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each Ctrl In ThisListBox.Parent.Controls
        If Ctrl.Name <> ThisListBox.Name And TypeName(Ctrl) = "ListBox" Then
            For i = 0 To Ctrl.ListCount - 1
                Ctrl.Selected(i) = False
            Next i
        End If
    Next Ctrl
End Sub
```

The code works and updates text boxes and listbox's without any problem it is when I close it or as I have just found out when I try and open another excel workbook. The new workbook does not open unless I close this workbook first. I believe it is an action waiting for something but can not see what.

Comment: Why isn't the `Terminate` handler not setting *both* MSForms control references to `Nothing`?

Comment: Both  MSForms  have been added to the Terminate and I am still getting the same error. Will not close and will not let any other workbook open until I go into Task Manager and close

Comment: Ok I'll try to take a deeper look later (I merely skimmed through the code) and repro on my machine.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was my work machine and its add on's so I put on my personal one and same issue.